# King of Tokyo: Number of points/hearts

Tags: king-of-tokyo

On the monster cards, there are dials for both hearts and stars. The start dial goes up to 20 because that's the point at which a player would win.

Does a player need to hit 20 stars exactly to win? Or can they have more?
How high does the heart dial go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not have to hit 20 points exactly, you just need at least 20. While the rulebook doesn't state this explicitly, this is how pretty much every game works unless it specifically states otherwise. Getting 21 points DOES mean that you've gotten 20 points; just like how I literally do have $20 even if I also have more money than that.

The heart dial goes to 12 because certain card effects can increase your health above 10.